# Unexprected behaviour making EAR for multiple spring boot war's returns a 1k EAR

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I need to pack all microservices made with Spring Boot into one big EAR.

The project is organized like this:

```
/root   
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle   
    /project1
        build.gradle
        ...
    /project3
        build.gradle
        ...
    /project3
        build.gradle
        ...
```

The root settings.gradle contains:

```
rootProject.name = "mysystem"

include("project1")
include("project2")
include("project3")
```

The build.gradle in root contains

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

allprojects {
  group = 'de.example'
}

dependencies {
  deploy project(path:':project1', configuration:'archives')
  deploy project(path:':project2', configuration:'archives')
  deploy project(path:':project3', configuration:'archives')
}



ear {
    deploymentDescriptor {
        applicationName = "myproject"
        initializeInOrder = true
        displayName = "My Project"
        description = "My Project EAR"
    }
}
```

The project build.gradle looks like

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
  }
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
defaultTasks 'bootWar'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  // Maven Spring Repository for Milestone Releases (optional for development but don't use it in Production)
  maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local' }
  // Maven Spring Repository for Stable Releases
  maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local' }
}

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.RELEASE'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter") {
  }
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json')
  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
  }
  providedCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
}
```

When I run gradle bootWar per project it generates the WAR in build/lib per project.

But when I run gradle ear in the root project, the output is like this:

```
Working Directory: D:\Workspace\root
Gradle User Home: D:\Workspace\.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 4.3
Java Home: C:\Programme\Java\jdk8
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: ear

Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:project1:compileJava
:project2:compileJava
:project3:compileJava
:project1:processResources
:project1:classes
:project1:war SKIPPED
:project2:processResources
:project2:classes
:project2:war SKIPPED
:project3:processResources
:project3:classes
:project3:war SKIPPED
:ear

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
7 actionable tasks: 7 executed
```

The result is an EAR with 1k size. There is no WAR generated per project. When I run gradle bootWar on every project and then run gradle ear, it works and the resulting EAR has 130Mb and includes all WARs.

Is there a way, that I only need to run gradle ear and it generates the WARs from bootWar?

Answer (score 1):

In a gradle Spring Boot project the "war" task is disabled in lieu of the "bootWar" task.

Setup the "ear" task in the parent build.gradle to depend on the "bootWar" task(s).

```
ear {
  dependsOn ':project1:bootWar'
}
```